# Having problems with aligning text in html

Tags: php, html

Ok I am having trouble aligning text and images within a table and browser in general. I have wrote all the code but I am having trouble in three areas:

1. The image and text are not aligning right, the desired result should look like the following:

[image]

2. More specifically, I cannot make the area and perimeter underneath each other. I even added the \n but it is not working.
3. Within the PHP formulas one of them is not working, I localized it to one formula in particular it is this one that is giving me problems:

$hypo = number_format(sqrt(pow(2 , 10.2) * pow(2 , 5.4), 2);

My entire code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Author:Randy Gilman
-->
<!--Table one-->
<?php
$cir_area = number_format(M_PI * pow(2 , 2.65), 2);
$cir_circum = number_format(2 * M_PI * 2.65, 2);
$rect_area = 4.2 * 5.6;
$rect_per = (2 * 4.2) + (2 * 5.6);
$tri_area = number_format(5.4 * (10.2/2), 2);
$hypo = number_format(sqrt(pow(2 , 10.2) * pow(2 , 5.4), 2);
$tri_per = number_format(5.4 + 10.2 + $hypo, 2);
$sqr_area = number_format(pow(2 , 5.3), 2);
$sqr_per = number_format(5.3 * 4, 2); 
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Randy's Table</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table border = "5px">
    <tr>
        <th> Circle
             <IMG SRC="http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/shapes/images/drawingtargetppt2010_02.jpg" ALT="circle" ALIGN=Right style="width:52px;height:52px;border:0;">
         <?php echo "Area = $cir_area square meters";
                   echo "\nCircumference = $cir_circum meters"; ?> 
        </th>
        <th> Rectangle 
             <IMG SRC="http://image.tutorvista.com/cms/images/38/rectangle-figure1.jpg" ALT="rectangle" ALIGN=Right style="width:52px;height:52px;border:0;">
         <?php echo "Area = $rect_area square meters";
                   echo "\nPerimeter = $rect_per meters"; ?> 
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Right Triangle 
             <IMG SRC="http://dasha46.narod.ru/Encyclopedic_Knowledge/Mathematics/Shapes/right_triangle.jpg" ALT="circle" ALIGN=Right style="width:52px;height:52px;border:0;">
         <?php echo "Area = $tri_area square meters";
                   echo "\nPerimeter = $tri_per meters"; ?> 
        </th>
        <th> Square 
             <IMG SRC="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg/600px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg.png" ALT="square" ALIGN=Right style="width:52px;height:52px;border:0;">
         <?php echo "Area = $sqr_area square meters";
                   echo "\nPerimeter = $rect_per meters"; ?> 
        </th>
    </tr>

       </table>
       </body>
<!--End of table one-->
</html>
```

Additionally, here is what my code produces currently if I remove the $hypo formula:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your mathematical formulas are wrong. Again.

Comment: The only one not working is the $hypo one. I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formulas are wrong. [`pow(2, 3)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) is `2` to the power of `3` which is `8`. Here and there you need to compute `X * X` which is `X` to the power of `2` i.e. `pow(X, 2)`.

Even if `pow($x, 2)` seems to be smarter than `$x * $x` it is not. It's harder to read and understand and it runs slower because it involves a function call and function calls always take time to be processed.

The formula of the [hypotenuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotenuse) of a square triangle is `sqrt(a*a+b*b)`. In terms of your code this is:

```
$hypo = sqrt(10.2 * 10.2 + 5.4 * 5.4);
```

As a general recommendation, **do not** mix the computation of values with their display, not even with the preparations for display. Compute all the values as numbers then use `number_format()` in the HTML part, just for display.

Regarding the HTML formatting, read the other answers and/or search the web for [HTML line break](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+line+break).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot that makes sense I was worried when I wrote it that adding to many functions in it would mess it up thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's an answer for #2**

You need to use HTML line breaks `<br />`, browsers ignore new lines in the code when creating the page.

As an example, for your Square section...

```
<th>
    Square 
    <IMG ... />
    <br />
    <?php echo "Area = $sqr_area square meters"; ?>
    <br />
    <?php echo "Perimeter = $rect_per meters"; ?> 
</th>
```

Comment: That cleared it up I used <br> though the <br  /> wasn't working maybe its the version I'm using

Answer (score 1):

you can use `<br>` tag to return line

example

```
     <th> 
Circle <IMG SRC="http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/shapes/images/drawingtargetppt2010_02.jpg" ALT="circle" ALIGN=Right style="width:52px;height:52px;border:0;">

 Area = <?=$rect_area square meters?><br/>

Perimeter = <?=$rect_per meters?>
</th>
```